# Lockar SELECT quando faço um UPDATE - SQLServer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Vou dar um exemplo do que estou fazendo, mas a pergunta mesmo está no final.

Tenho uma tabela com 4.100.000 registros e estou criando um robo que lê esses dados e exporta para o MYSQL(não entra em pauta, apenas para ambientar).

Eu tenho duas colunas `BIT`, uma se chama processing e a outra migrated, num loop infinito executo esse comando

```
SELECT TOP 100 Title,Tamanho,Caption,dataHoraIndexacao,Date,Resolucao,Base,Altura,orientacao,codigo,NomeArquivo FROM migracao.Reuters WHERE processing = 0 and migrated = 0
```

Pretendo executar varios robos ao mesmo tempo para poder agilizar o processo, a questão é, quando eu faço o `SELECT` logo após a população da minha List no c#, eu dou um update em todos os itens como `processing = 1` e isso leva um tempo, imagine que enquanto dou o `UPDATE` um outro robo da um `SELECT` e retorna os mesmos dados que eu estou dando `UPDATE`, ou seja informações duplicadas.

**A pergunta é**: Como lockar uma tabela enquanto dou um `UPDATE` na mesma?

Comment: Editei a pergunta , na verdade é quando dou um UPDATE e não um SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Se quiser bloquear a tabela para escrita até o término de uma transação use:

```
Code Snippet
SELECT * FROM TABELA (HOLDLOCK)
```

Se quiser bloquear a tabela para leitura e escrita até o término de uma transação use:

```
Code Snippet
SELECT * FROM TABELA (XLOCK)
```

Lembre-se de que impor bloqueios a tabela inteira poderá diminuir a concorrência e introduzir lentidão em seu banco de dados (mais processos terão de esperar até que o bloqueio da tabela termine).

Comment: Marcelo,preciso lockar a leitura até o momento em que eu finalizar o UPDATE, mas enquanto isso haverão INSERTS rolando em outros processos, SELECT pode esperar tranquilo, a melhor opção seria (XLOCK)  então, correto?

Comment: Acredito que sim, Leonardo. Mas o melhor mesmo é testar os dois e ver qual se adequa melhor a sua necessidade.